# Citation of Reports from Environmental Agency

Tags: citations, citation-style

I need to cite a report from different Agencies. I have never cited a report before, and on the Internet, I only found how to cite papers, books, or theses. Can anyone give me a good example or help me with my one? This is the way I cited them:

> (1) USEPA. Guidance for Assessing Pesticide Risks to BeesU.S. Environmental Protection Agency (USEPA) Health Canada Pest Management Regulatory Agency (PMRA) and California Department of Pesticide Regulation. Off. Pestic. Programs USEPA, Heal. Canada PMRA, CDPR 2014
> (2) European Food Safety Authority. Evaluation of the Data on Clothianidin, Imidacloprid and Thiamethoxam for the Updated Risk Assessment to Bees for Seed Treatments and Granules in the EU; 2018; Vol. 15.

But for me, it looks a little bit strange. I know there are a lot of ways to cite. This is the normal way I cite my papers:

> (3) Zhao, J.; Long, L.; Weng, G.; Li, J.; Zhu, J.; Zhao, J. W. Multi-Branch Au/Ag Bimetallic Core-Shell-Satellite Nanoparticles as a Versatile SERS Substrate: The Effect of Au Branches in a Mesoporous Silica Interlayer. J. Mater. Chem. C 2017, 5 (48), 12678–12687

Comment: Your citation style will depend upon where you are publishing. Journals have their own style that range from including government reports in the reference section to treating them as _in line_ references because the reports are usually not peer reviewed. Thesis or dissertation will depend upon your school and advisor

Answer (score 2):

Most citation styles follow the basic principle of: `Who`-`When`-`What`-`Where`, or `Author`-`Date`-`Title`-`Source`. Your "normal way" of citing follows a variant of this.

Based on this principle, the APA manual (to name but one example) shows [how to cite a governmental report](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/report-government-agency-references):

> National Cancer Institute. (2019). Taking time: Support for people
> with cancer (NIH Publication No. 18-2059). U.S. Department of Health
> and Human Services, National Institutes of Health.
> https://www.cancer.gov/publications/patient-education/takingtime.pdf

The manual tells us: "The specific agency responsible for the report appears as the author. The names of parent agencies not present in the group author name appear in the source element as the publisher. This creates concise in-text citations and complete reference list entries."

---

Applied to your case, I would suggest your reference to be as the follolwing (in APA style, but you can change the format - such as the position of the year of publication - according to your needs):

> Environmental Protection Agency. (2014). Guidance for Assessing Pesticide Risks to Bees. Federal Government of the United States. https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2014-06/documents/pollinator_risk_assessment_guidance_06_19_14.pdf

and:

> European Food Safety Authority. (2018). Evaluation of the Data on Clothianidin, Imidacloprid and Thiamethoxam for the Updated Risk Assessment to Bees for Seed Treatments and Granules in the Eu. European Union. https://doi.org/10.2903/sp.efsa.2018.EN-1378